# Problema con useEffect y etiqueta video en Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html-video, useeffect

estoy intentando tomar un video html sin controles y personalizar los mismos, presento el problema que necesito que mi linea de tiempo se actualice constantemente con el `currentTime` del video, uso los hook de la api de react `useRef` para el video `useState` para cambiar el `currentTime` de mi componente y `useEffect` para intentar cambiar el `currentTime` el código es el siguiente.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    
    export const Video = ({ url }) => {
        const player = useRef(null)
        const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
        const [prueba, setPrueba] = useState(0);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setCurrentTime(player.current.currentTime);
    
        }, [prueba]);
        
        const pruebita = () => {
            setPrueba(prueba+1);
        }

    return (
        <>
            <video
                ref={player}
                autoPlay
                src={url}
            ></video>
            <div>{currentTime}</div>
            <button onMouseDown={ pruebita }>clickeame muy seguido</button >
        </>
    )
}
```

La idea es general es mismo efecto que se genera al tener pruebita y prueba, pero sin ningun evento componente.

Espero me puedan ayudar saludos.

Comment: Te gustaría que se muestre la hora actual sin hacer clic en el botón? Porque tu código está funcionando.

Comment: en realidad lo que necesito es recuperar en tiempo real el segundo o instante en que el video esta reproduciendose como cuando en youtube pueds ver el tiempo del instante en que va el video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no me complicaría y utilizaría un `setInterval` para sincronizar el tiempo con el de tu componente de React, recuerda destruir el `setInterval` por medio del cleanup del hook, sería algo cómo así:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    
    export const Video = ({ url }) => {
        const player = useRef(null)
        const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
        const [prueba, setPrueba] = useState(0);
    
        useEffect(() => {
          const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCurrentTime(player.current.currentTime);
          }, 900);
          return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }, [currentTime]);

    return (
        <>
            <video
                ref={player}
                autoPlay
                src={url}
            ></video>
            <div>{currentTime}</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

### Sandbox, cortesía de [milmal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/195461/milmal)

[Aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-dewdney-9ok1u?file=/src/App.js) está el demo. Muchas gracias milmal por el código reproducible y también por agregar el redondeo de los decimales de los segundos.

### Update

No entiendo porque te renderiza infinitamente, supongo que estás teniendo un problema con un elemento padre... Mira este ejemplo, en el que uso la misma lógica y no presenta ningún tipo de error:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
    
const Video = () => {
        const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
    
        useEffect(() => {
          const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCurrentTime(currentTime +1);
          }, 1000);
          return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }, [currentTime]);

    return (
            <div>{`Han pasado ${currentTime} segundos`}</div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Video/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: sonaba muy bien pero tengo el siguiente error, es el mismo error que me ha jodido la existencia `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Comment: Qué extraño, edité la pregunta. ¿Puedes echarle un vistazo al código que puse sin el video?

Comment: El primer ejemplo de @FranAcuna funciona. ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-dewdney-9ok1u?file=/src/App.js)). El único cambio que te recomiendo hacer es usar `Math.floor(player.current.currentTime)` para obtener los segundos enteros.

Comment: Muchas gracias @milmal, voy a agregar tu sandbox a la respuesta y hacer la edición que sugieres.

Comment: vi sus comentarios y comencé a revisar un poco mejor mi código, me di cuenta que tenía un código que era el que me presentaba el error, el cual había programado para otra función y aquel era el que presentaba el error, el código de la respuesta inicial y editada funcionan perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: gracias a @milmal por su sandbox